# How to validate class type in Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, typechecking

I have a function which accepts an instance of a class as a parameter. Using Flow for static typechecking, I want to ensure that only instances of a specific class or a classes which extend it are accepted.

For example say I have:

```
class Foo {
  doSomething (): boolean {
  return true
  // ...other fields/methods...
}


class Bar extends Foo
```

And then I have a method like:

```
function myFunction(fooInstance) {
  return fooInstance.doSomething()
}
```

Could I add Flow annotation to ensure that only instances of Foo or a child class like Bar are passed to `myFunction()`?

Comment: I'm not an expert but shouldn't `fooInstance: Foo` work?

Comment: @AndrewLi I tried and it does not seem to work. Flow allows me to annotate like that but then does not give me errors if I pass in a different type.

Comment: Just tried in TryFlow and it @Andrew suggestion seems to work -> https://tryflow.org/?code=LyogQGZsb3cgKi8KY2xhc3MgRm9vIHsKICBkb1NvbWV0aGluZyAoKTogYm9vbGVhbiB7CiAgICByZXR1cm4gdHJ1ZQogIH0KICAvLyAuLi5vdGhlciBmaWVsZHMvbWV0aG9kcy4uLgp9CgoKY2xhc3MgQmFyIGV4dGVuZHMgRm9vIHt9CgpsZXQgYmFyID0gbmV3IEJhcigpOwoKZnVuY3Rpb24gbXlGdW5jdGlvbihmb29JbnN0YW5jZTogRm9vKSB7CiAgcmV0dXJuIGZvb0luc3RhbmNlLmRvU29tZXRoaW5nKCkKfQoKbXlGdW5jdGlvbihiYXIpOwpteUZ1bmN0aW9uKHt9KTs=

Comment: @Keith thanks! I'm using react native so maybe there is an issue with react's implementation?

Comment: @EricaCooksey React uses Flow. No modifications. Are you sure that's all your code? Give us an example more specific to your case

Comment: btw. Your example code for class Foo has a missing `}`, it's not that whats giving you problems is it?.  I'm assuming it's just a cut & paste error, but maybe worth a mention.

Comment: @Keith no it isn't like that in my actual code, but thanks for pointing it out!